# If `w` is FALSE, `x` is FALSE, and `y` is TRUE, what is `((x OR y) AND (y AND w)') OR (x AND y' AND w')`?

Tags: logic

## My thought process:
x or y = true
and
y and w = false

false

or

x and not y = false and false = false
and
true

false = false ?

I'm not sure where I'm wrong here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where you went wrong because you haven't expressed the working clearly.  But here's what I get.

> If `w` is FALSE, `x` is FALSE, and `y` is TRUE, what is `((x OR y) AND (y AND w)') OR (x AND y' AND w')`?

```
((x OR y) AND (y AND w)') OR (x AND y' AND w')
```

Replace suffix `'` with prefix `NOT` ... 'cos I think it is clearer

```
((x OR y) AND NOT (y AND w)) OR (x AND NOT y AND NOT w)
```

Substitute values for variables

```
((FALSE OR TRUE) AND NOT (TRUE AND FALSE)) OR (FALSE AND NOT TRUE AND NOT FALSE)
```

Reduce

```
((TRUE) AND NOT (FALSE)) OR (FALSE AND FALSE AND TRUE)
```

Reduce

```
(TRUE AND TRUE) OR (FALSE)
```

Reduce

```
TRUE OR FALSE
```

Reduce

```
TRUE
```

Lesson: show your complete working, like they told you in your math classes.

Comment: Thanks so much - can I run this by you? I got true                                                                        
        If `w` is FALSE, `x` is TRUE, and `y` is FALSE, what is `((w OR y') AND (x' AND y')') OR ((w OR y')' AND (x OR y)')'`?

    I get true, can you verify? My thoughts:

   w or not y= true
    not x and not y= false
    w or not y= true
    x or y= true
   true or false = true

Comment: Just do it longhand like I did.  Or write a simple program in your favorite programming language to evaluate it as a boolean expression.